# Why is this matrix positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, poissons-equation

Our teacher told us that the following matrix is definite positive, how to prove it?

Note: this is not an excercise, I simply do not like to believe one's words without a proof.

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 & 0 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
-1 & 2 & -1 & \ldots & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 & \ddots & \ddots &\vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 2 & -1 \\ 
0 & 0 &\ldots & -1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Curiosity: this matrix comes out when trying to solve numerically the Poisson equation in one dimension.

Comment: It is in fact possible to write down every eigenvector of this matrix explicitly and just check that all of its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: This is Toeplitz tridiagonal, so its eigenvalues are $2+2\cos(k\pi/(n+1))$, for $k=1,2,\dots,n$, hence positive. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Eigenvalues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $z^T$ has the values $(a,b,c,\ldots, j,k)$

then you may be able to show $$z^T M z = a^2 +(b-a)^2+(c-b)^2+\ldots +(k-j)^2+k^2$$ which is non-negative as a sum of squares, and is only zero when all the elements  in $z$ are equal and are zero